# Is it acceptable to post an answer to my own question?

Tags: discussion, support

I spent many hours researching on Stack Overflow for help on a particular programming challenge. I didn't find an answer close enough to what I was looking for. I was going to post a new question, but as I was writing it up I kept thinking of new approaches. Eventually I was able to write a function to solve the problem.

My question is, for the benefit of the community, can I post a question and the answer immediately?  Is this frowned upon? Can I accept my own answer?

A secondary question, and maybe unrelated to Meta, is there a place on Stack Exchange to share code snippets? In this case my question relates to VBA and regular expressions.

Comment: Yes, this is acceptable, per the FAQ [Can I answer my own questions, even if I knew the answer before asking?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-if-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking)

Comment: As a matter of fact, when you reach 15 rep, there's an option to post your answer immediately at the time you post your question.

Answer (score 0):

From a "related" link that popped up after I posted this question, it seems that it is acceptable and encouraged to answer your own questions if at least one other person can benefit from it.  (I searched meta before asking this question.  Really, I did!)

[Posting and answering questions you have already found the answer to](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2706/posting-and-answering-questions-you-have-already-found-the-answer-to?rq=1)

Comment: Ironically answering your own question can quickly generate down votes if it is discovered as a duplicate.  Go easy.  I'm new and I want to contribute.

Comment: That is why it is a good idea to always post comments to both the question and the answer to such self-answered questions, explaining why self-answering is OK, perhaps also linking to the meta question about self-answering.